# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Don't know what to do

Tags: laravel-9, artisan-migrate

I'm using a MacbookPro M1. I am trying to run `php artisan migrate`, but it keeps giving me this error message.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema = library-app and
> table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Here's my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=library-app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password123
```

I tried looking everywhere on the Internet but to no avail.
I need assistance since I have no more options.

Update:
I tried changing `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `localhost` and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Sounds like your application cannot properly connect to the database - did this work before?

Comment: Yes in another project but I don't know why it's like this now.

Comment: So where is your database? Are you using Docker, or do you really have it running on your local machine?  Can you connect to it with a MySQL client?

Comment: Have you tried connecting without a db_password? I had a similar issue, but this was on my windows (using wsl). I managed to get it working at the end of the day